# My djanco configuration fail to download images but store them in the db without occuring any error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm dealing with a problem I have since 2 days, i'm trying to store an image for a car website in a database other than my car one, the creation is successful, it appears in the database but when I try to store the same image in a folder of my application, whatever I try it simply doesn't work, here's my models :

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    marque          = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    modele          = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    motorisation    = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    couleur         = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    carburant       = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    annee_modele    = models.IntegerField()
    kilometrage     = models.IntegerField()
    nbr_porte       = models.IntegerField()
    nbr_place       = models.IntegerField()
    puiss_fiscale   = models.IntegerField()    #En chevaux fiscaux
    puiss_din       = models.IntegerField()    #En chevaux DIN

    a_vendre        = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class CarImage(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Cars, related_name="images", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='car_images/')models.py
```

```
Post view :

class manage_cars(View):

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        c_serializer = car_serializer(data=request.POST)
        
        if c_serializer.is_valid():
            car_instance = c_serializer.save()
            
            images = request.FILES.getlist('image')
            print(images)
            for image in images:
                
                image_path = handle_uploaded_image(car_instance, image)
            
                # Créer l'objet CarImage avec le chemin de l'image
                CarImage.objects.create(car=car_instance, image=image_path)
            
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Voiture et images sauvegardées avec succès"}, status=201)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(car_serializer.errors, status=400)
```

```
serializers.py 

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class car_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        fields = "__all__"serializers.py
```

```
settings.py :

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

I'm just a french newbie in back-end development it's probably some stupid stuff that cause the error but i'm so sick of it...

i tried to give my "media" and "car_images" folders full-control rights and other things that didn't work

Comment: it appears in the database but when I try to store the same image in a folder of my application? What does that mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Pycm it doesn't raise any error, i try to save the file into the database (more precisely the path and the id of the car it is linked to) but when i try to download it to my folder (media/car_images) it doesn't show any image inside

Comment: `but when i try to download it to my folder (media/car_images) it doesn't show any image inside ` what do you mean by download it to my folder? Explain exactly what you did?